# Any ideas for a dissertation?

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, projects

I was wondering whether anyone had some ideas for a dissertation i have to do for university. It will be a 12 month project and I will probably be looking to do something in c++ but I'm open to anything. I was thinking about looking in AI but not sure.

Thank in adv.

Comment: As someone thinking of going back for my Ph.D. (after 25 years in the field), thanks for bring up the subject....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to look for people who work in this field at your university and ask them for project suggestions. You will eventually end up with someone from yor Uni as a supervisor anyway, so why not get in touch with them right away?

On the other hand, if you really want some suggestions, look at the numerous AI competitions that are on the web.

http://www.thousandparsec.net/tp/comp.php 
http://eis.ucsc.edu/StarCraftAICompetition

... and more

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ai+competition

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realise this is possible but i thought by asking on here i'd get more ideas than just asking one person.

Comment: You are welcome, i hope my answer helped you a bit. Good luck with your dissertation!

Answer (score 2):

As someone who has just been though a dissertation I'll agree with Peter and say the 100% best thing to do is seek out your supervisor. Typically you'll end up doing a project that is close to their field of expertise and often they'll have something in mind for you, again normally branching off from their own research or the research of their PhD's.

The other piece of advice for you is to try and choose a project that genuinely interests you, its hard to keep the focus required to properly research something if you don't personally find it interesting!

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest to have a look at an open source project? In particular, projects participating in the [Google Summer Of Code](http://code.google.com/soc/) initiative ([here's a list](http://socghop.appspot.com/gsoc/program/accepted_orgs/google/gsoc2010)) often maintain a list of interesting ideas for students. Those are usually tailored to be completed during the summer, but it could be an interesting starting point nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been asked few years ago, it is still relevant for many hew PhD students. Therefore, I suggest that you, the new PhD student read carefully the following documents available on the section "Resources" of  the ["PhD Candidate" page](http://bit.ly/yQegxq) :

1. "How to Get a Ph.D." by Estelle M. Phillips ;
2. "Choosing Your Thesis or Dissertation Topic" (U. of California)
3. "How to Succeed in Graduate School: a Guide for Students and Advisors "

Happy reading. Although this question has been asked few years ago, it is still relevant for many hew PhD students. Therefore, I suggest that you, the new PhD student read carefully the following documents available on the section "Resources" of  the ["PhD Candidate" page](http://bit.ly/yQegxq) :

1. "How to Get a Ph.D." by Estelle M. Phillips ;
2. "Choosing Your Thesis or Dissertation Topic" (U. of California)
3. "How to Succeed in Graduate School: a Guide for Students and Advisors "